# Developing iOS 7 apps on PhoneGap not an option anymore after February 1th? (Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK restriction!)

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios7

Yesterday I've received a mail from the Apple Developer Center, stating:

*Make sure your apps work seamlessly with the innovative technologies in iOS 7. Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK.*

Will this mean the end of developing apps cross-device off of non-Apple devices?
It sure is a heavy restriction and I'm very disappointed with this news!

Could someone shine a light on this painful news?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is the case.

As long as the app is compiled using XCode, and using the iOS7 SDK, you should be fine.

When they say "built" they mean, it has a corresponding XCode project. Not that every line of code has been written in XCode. At least, that's my interpretation.

Comment: You are correct. What they mean is that when you actually compile the release version of your ipa file for submission to Apple, it needs to be compiled using Xcode5 and IOS7 SDK. You can still use phonegap and anything else you have used in the past.

Comment: So does this mean that neither the base SDK or deployment SDK cannot be 6.x or below?

Comment: Thanks Dawson & shepsii. I guess I'll have no choice of using the Mac then. That's then, in my opinion, a horrible restriction of Apple.
Maybe PhoneGap uses xcode in their compiler? :)

Comment: PhoneGap is not a "compiler" -- it is really more of a "linker/masher/munger" of pieces and parts. When you use PhoneGap (or Cordova) it will invoke the Xcode compiler to perform it's magic, but it does not provide the compiler -- you need a Mac with Xcode installed to "build" PhoneGap/Cordova apps locally. Otherwise, you can use a cloud service, which does the same on the backend ("in the cloud").