# Developing iOS 7 apps on intel-XDK not an option anymore after February 1st?

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

I need to ask the same question from this thread :

[Developing iOS 7 apps on PhoneGap not an option anymore after February 1th? (Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK restriction!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109889/developing-ios-7-apps-on-phonegap-not-an-option-anymore-after-february-1th-xco)

Will apps created using intel XDK becomes unusable, due to this new policy changes?

Thanks.

Edit: Updated the question.

Comment: What is it you're asking, exactly?

Comment: Sorry for missing the question. I've edited my question above. I also change the title to say "intel XDK" instead of "phonegap".