# Will I be able to submit iOS PhoneGap Build apps after February 1?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

From February 1, apple is changing the rules for submitting apps to the app store. All apps will have to be build using iOS 7 SDK and will have to be compiled with xcode.
I am afraid that this might mean that all my projects built with Adobe Phonegap Build will be useless (ones that use Phonegap build plugins that are not locally available).

I am aware of **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109889/developing-ios-7-apps-on-phonegap-not-an-option-anymore-after-february-1th-xco)** question.

However that question only talks about PhoneGap (cordova), and not PhoneGap Build specifically.

With Phonegap (cordova) I can build apps locally and an xcode project gets generated, so that will not prevent people from submitting apps as in the end you will still build it with xcode.

However, with Adobe PhoneGap build, the app binary is compiled on adobe's servers and not on my installation of xcode, and that service does not generate an xcode project.

So my question is, will these PhoneGap Build generated apps be accepted by apple or not? I am afraid that I am right by thinking that they will not be accepted, but just want to make sure, so if you know more about this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the statement from Apple only means that apps built with Xcode version < 5 and not optimised for iOS7 are not accepted any longer - not that you cannot submit apps built with different frameworks (if they are compliant to their new UI guidelines, of course).

Comment: how do the UI guidelines limit me? Can I still use any graphics and button styles I want in my app to match my brand? I was thinking that if I make everything flat and simplistic like iOS 7 then my app will not reflect my brand and thats a problem.

Comment: I would think more in lines of "it shouldn't look like it's an iOS 5 app". So don't use skeumorphism, try to integrate the status bar into the whole view (if you have one), make sure it works nicely on iPhone 5 (larger screen). Up to now I did not have much problems with using any UI I needed.

Comment: Then hopefully my UI will be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry about this. Apple basically said they will no longer allow apps that are built using the iOS 6 SDK / Xcode 4. I don't expect other changes in their policies and didn't hear a big outcry on Twitter either :)